# Using Git for customer's software

Tags: git

I'm looking to gather a little bit of information on the topic of using Git as a means by which to manage my companies, customer environments. That was a bit wordy.

We have been manually setting up customers environments for a few decades now, but are looking to automate a bit of the process and ensure that everyone is version controlled. We have since set up a few repositories and a jenkins build machine for this purpose. I am curious as to how to move forward. Should all customers be on the same repository, but different branches of the repository based on various factors?

With a hundred or so customers, each customer having their own repository or branch may be a little overkill. My initial thought was that since all programs, minus data and config files, are kept within version control, there would be a branch for several different versions of our software. For example, these could be Alpha, Beta, and so on. After changes are considered stable, I suspect that branches would be merged (Alpha into Beta) or changelists would be cherry picked. Although that seems as if it would be a very cumbersome process.

Any reading material is greatly appreciated. I actually found [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177816/collaboration-using-github-and-testing-the-code), and the first answer was extremely helpful in modeling our future testing and deployment.

Comment: We don't know anything about what you're keeping in version control.

Comment: I've updated OP with another post that more clearly defines what we have in version control and what I'm looking to do. Just am unsure if it's a wise idea :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, branches are mostly used in one of the following situations:

1. The branches will eventually be merged together (e.g., a local development branch)
2. The branches are not expected to be very active and will eventually die (e.g., a branch for a release and some bugfixes)

You can use branches to manage multiple similar configurations over a long time, if that is what you are asking, but I don't think it is very maintainable. Especially, if you have many customers (branches) to keep track of.

Unfortunately, I don't know much about your concrete problem, but it seems that each customer should get one separate repository. However, if there is shared configuration between the customers, there might be a better way to model the problem (instead of copying the shared configuration in every repository, or using branches).

Comment: Updated OP with more information. Most customers have the same basic setup, just some have different versions of the various programs within our package.